# Spring Data JPA batch inserts

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a basic SpringBoot app with repositories that extends JpaRepository and services in which repos are injected. I'm trying to batch insert by looking here: https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-batch-insert-and-update-statements-with-hibernate/
When trying to open a transaction, I get an error `Not allowed to create transaction on shared EntityManager - use Spring transactions or EJB CMT instead`
I mention that I have `@EnableTransactionManagement` so that's why I can't create transactions by myself. What are my options?

Comment: Why do you try opening a transaction, since Spring does that for you using declarative transaction management?

Comment: @JBNizet I'm trying to do a batch insert. For this I am following this blog post: https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-do-batch-processing-with-jpa-and-hibernate/ For this I need to commit transaction periodically.

Comment: The post shows that you need to split the large batch into several smaller transactions. Whether you open and commit/rollback them yourself, programmatically, or let Spring do that for you dosn't change the idea. So just let Spring open and commit/rollback them for you.Have a service A call a service B in a loop, where each call to B executes a slice of the batch, in a new transaction.

Comment: @JBNizet yes, that's what I also realized immediately after writing this question here on SO. Thank you very much, and if you think this question could still help someone, write your comment as an answer and I'll accept it :)

Comment: @JBNizet One more question. Sorry for this. Right now it saves entries to DB , but it doesn't seems to be doing in batch. I have hibernate.show_sql and I get multiple insert into table values statements instead of only one insert into table and multiple values. Like in that post I linked I would've expected something like this: INSERT INTO post (title, id) values (?, ?)"], 
Params:[
    (Post 26, 26), (Post 27, 27), (Post 28, 28), 
    (Post 29, 29), (Post 30, 30), (Post 31, 31)
]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The post shows that you need to split the large batch into several smaller transactions. Whether you open and commit/rollback them yourself, programmatically, or let Spring do that for you, doesn't change the idea.

So just let Spring open and commit/rollback them for you. Have a service A call a service B in a loop, where each call to B executes a slice of the batch, in a new, declarative, transaction.